# vb.net : background worker causing delay in UI

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am running a background worker to gather some information before I show the user a log in screen. I have the call to the log in page inside the workerCompleted sub, but for the first few seconds that the log in page shows, the mouse moves very jerky and you can't click any buttons, then everything works fine after a couple of seconds. It looks like the background worker isn't really finished, but it showed me the log in page anyway. Is there a way to determine if the background worker is REALLY finished before moving on?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
Private check_config_bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker

Public Sub start()

  check_config_bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
  check_config_bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
  AddHandler check_config_bw.DoWork, AddressOf check_config_bw_DoWork
  AddHandler check_config_bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf check_config_bw_ProgressChanged
  AddHandler check_config_bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf check_config_bw_RunWorkerCompleted

  If Not check_config_bw.IsBusy = True Then
     check_config_bw.RunWorkerAsync()
  End If

End Sub

Private Sub check_config_bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
 ' open database connection, check it, move on
End Sub

Private Sub check_config_bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)

        ' dispose of the background worker since it is no longer needed
        ' ------------------------------------------------------------
        check_config_bw.Dispose()

        If check_config_success = True Then

            ' Go on to the next step
            ' ----------------------
            show_login()

        Else
            ' go to configuration page
            ' ------------------------
            configure_application() 

        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Worker_completed event? How about some code there is likely another issue.

Comment: I don't believe you want to call the Dispose in the WorkCompleted event.  I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: Try replacing `show_login` with `With New Form().ShowDialog() : End With` and see if this opens slowly too.

Comment: And you can get the status of the worker in the WorkerCompleted method by using the e.Cancelled or e.Error properties.  You can see a very high level example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: OK, After doing more research, I've found that the problem does not show up in Windows7, Vista or Server2008. It does show up in WindowsXP and Server2003. I have my CPU setting to x86 in the Publish settings and I'm using the .net4 framework. Is there anything special I need to do for older OS's?